# Getting graphical buttons to line up in xml

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a custom popup window with a custom image background in which I need to place three custom buttons with their own background images. I have only one set of images for all the components, so I want all the parts to scale appropriately. My question now is how do I make sure that the buttons line up with the appropriate parts of the background image of the popup window. I have been experimenting with all sorts of widths and heights and I can not make it look consistent on all my test devices. Can anyone give me some pointers?

**EDIT:** Just to make it as clear as possible, the image below illustrates the kind of thing I am talking about:

[image]

I want the graphical button to line up with the arrows which are a part of the popup window background image.

Answer (score 0):

arrange buttons in an xml layout and set this view to your custom popup and you can set images to buttons from code.

Comment: But then how do I ensure that the non-custom text buttons appear in the right place relative to the background image?

Comment: I found that it was easier to get the buttons in the right place if they are text rather than graphical - but then in the code where I say setBackgroundResource() the button then changes size. What I'd like is a setBackgroundResourceButDontChangeSize() function.